# eth.syncing "highestBlock" meaning

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I am syncing the blockchain with geth and I type "eth.syncing" to check the progress.  I notice that "highestBlock" does not change.  It's the same as it was when I started syncing a few days ago.

I assume it refers to the highest block at the time I started.  So my question is what significance that has.  Will the RPC start to work when I catch up to "highestBlock" or only when I catch up to the actual, current highest block?

Answer (score 1):

"highestBlock" is last block number and should increase by 1 almost every 15 seconds.
If it is not increasing on your console, it may be because of you have some problem in syncing.

If you saw this problem at last few hundreds remaining blocks, one of most general problems can be your system time! Try to enable network time synchronisation on your computer and restart ethereum client after that may solve your problem.

You can use following command to enable NTP on Ubuntu.

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Comment: Thank you but "highestBlock" is not increasing.  Or was not.  I stopped using that server.  But after days that number did not increase.  ntp and ntp-date were running.